# Check if string is Match GetInvalidFileNameChars()

Tags: c#

I try to check  if string is Match `GetInvalidFileNameChars()`

i would like to use regex

So i put the chars of `GetInvalidFileNameChars()` into a string and then check

```
if Regex.IsMatch(id, stringInvalidFileName)
```

I thought if `id = "4711./"` then `Regex.IsMatch(id, stringInvalidFileName)`

should be true, but it's false

What is my mistake, why is it false ?! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use a regex?

This will work fine:

```
string s = "4711./";
if (Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars().Any( c => s.Contains(c))
```

As [Rawling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215380/rawling) points out below, when you're dealing with large strings it might be more efficient to use `Intersect` instead:

```
string longString = "Something much, much longer than this";
if (longString.Intersect(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()).Any())
```

For relatively short strings (file paths, for example) there's probably little if any benefit. I'd prefer the first option, as it more clearly conveys the code's intent, in my opinion.

Comment: Or you could use `Intersect` and not be `O(n^2)` :p

Comment: `Contains` returns immediately once a match is found, where as `Intersect` always needs to enumerate the entire string, so I doubt `Intersect` will give you any real benefits.

Comment: `Intersect(...).Any()` stops as soon as a match is found, and only iterates each input once.